# cant seem to update my values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update

So I have a form for a color palette that I would like to update live, I've been stuck with this problem for days.

this is my controller for update

```
def update
  @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:id])
    binding.pry
  @palette = @project.palette
  unless @project
    render json: {error: "project not found"},
    status: 404
    return
  end
  @project.update(project_params)
  @project.update_palette(palette_params)
  render json: project
end
```

one Project has one Palette

```
    private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :option, :id, :background_dark_color, :background_light_color, :dark_color1, :dark_color2, :light_color1, :light_color2)
end

def palette_params
        params.require(:palette).permit(:background_dark_color, :background_light_color, :dark_color1, :dark_color2, :light_color1, :light_color2) #=> [ :id, :name, :_destroy ])
end
```

the error is throwing to me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B37O.png)

Added form

```
              <%= palette.label 'background_dark_color' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :background_dark_color, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{@project.palette}" %><br/>

          <%= palette.label 'background_light_color' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :background_light_color, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{@project.palette}" %><br/>

          <%= palette.label 'dark_color1' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :dark_color1, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{}"  %><br/>

          <%= palette.label 'dark_color2' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :dark_color2, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{@project.palette}" %><br/>

          <%= palette.label 'light_color1' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :light_color1, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{@project.palette}"      %><br/>

          <%= palette.label 'light_color2' %>:
          <%= palette.text_field :light_color2, maxlength: 6, placeholder: "#{@project.palette}" %><br/>

          <%= palette.submit %>

          <%= link_to 'Destroy',  project,  method: :delete %>
           <!-- , data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } this is the confirm message and sucks, better use "undo" -->

        <% end %>
```

Comment: It is saying you have no params for your project being sent through, it is quite likely that the problem lies in your form view or possibly even the setting up of the instances in your edit action, can you provide your entire controller and view file also?

Comment: Post views as well

Comment: there they are thank you kind people

Comment: Check your ```@project``` in the view, make sure it's an instance of Project.

Comment: that is only part of your view, and still only part of your controller is available, if you want to get a decent answer thats not just a stab in the dark, you will need to provide the whole view and controller at least...